# declaring dynamic Schema in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
questionDetails =                                                   
{           
    question: String,                                                                 
    answer: [],
}
```

I'm interested in defining a Schema in Mongoose of a Question which can have multiple answers.

The above demonstrates, how the Schema may look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [webdocs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) explain it as below:-

```
var blogSchema = new Schema({
  author: String,
  comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  hidden: Boolean,
  meta: {
    votes: Number,
    favs:  Number
  }
});
```

The permitted SchemaTypes are

```
Array ,
String , 
Number ,
Date , 
Buffer ,
Boolean , 
Mixed ,
ObjectId
```